Force android kernel to detect insertion of sdcard
I have a device based on Android, where sdcard tray is fixed, because of that hotPlugging doesn't work. I need to repeat the same exact way in my custom kernel module, what it does when physically inserting sdcard to a tray.
Please advice, how to do that?
I tried to restart mmc host controller, but this resulted in system reboot

"sdcard tray is fixed" - What does this mean? By "tray" do you mean "socket"? what does "fixed" mean? "I tried to restart mmc host controller ..." - Directly interfering with a device managed by the kennel typically leads to system instability. The SD card socket has a signal for Card Detect, aka CD. This signal is typically used as the GPIO interrupt of the SD/MMC driver that indicates when a SD card is inserted or ejected.

tray is fixed means, that in micro sdcard socket, full-sized tray is fixed to enable full-sized sdcards. I cannot modify hardware of that device, and searching for software solutions.

@sawdust the problem is that we cannot use card detect line on hardware level, as in micro sd card socket we have fixed a full-sized sdcard socket.

If the device tree node for the MMC controller device has the non-removable; property, then the card is assumed to be always present. Alternatively, If it has the broken-cd; property, it will periodically poll the controller to detect the card.

Is there any way to check if device has such property?
